# How remap default key in VIM, without affecting the other remap?

Tags: vim, vi

So, I have the following keymap in my .vimrc

```
noremap <C-o> :browse confirm e<CR>
vnoremap <C-o> :browse confirm e<CR>
inoremap <C-o> :browse confirm e<CR>
```

This is for the GUI of GVIM. Then I will get a popup with file folder. Here I can select files.

But this disables the Control-o file jump (when you press Ctrl-o). I don't want that, but I want to hold the Ctrl-o map for the GUI folder view.  I still want use the folder jump.

So, I thought i could map the jump one file back from Control-o C-o to Alt-o. So the map would look like noremap  :jump 1g back in history, or something.

I tried everything, to see what the default command was when you give the Control-o  key for jumping back in the file history. I don't know how you see
the default command for the standard Control-o .

The :verbose map is only applicable for remapped keys.

Anyone have suggestions to find the right command for the default Control-o key?

Comment: You should try to stick with Vim's default as much as possible. If you want an interactive list of files to choose from, use `:Ex`. Also, navigating your filesystem doesn't make much sense outside of normal mode. On the same note, `<C-o>` *doesn't* jump you back in the file history at all, it jumps back in the jump list which is not the same thing *at all*. If you don't want to adjust to Vim's modality and learn how to use its default features there are many other editors available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some other programs have the concept of "key bindings" where there is a list of available internal commands, and then various keys are assigned to trigger these commands.  Vim does not work that way.  There is no <strike>spoon</strike> internal command triggered by `CTRL-O`.  What you can do is map `ALT-o` to `CTRL-O`.

I am not sure that `<M-o>` works for `ALT-o` on my system, but for the sake of discussion, let's assume that it does on yours.  If you were to define

```
:nnoremap <C-o> :browse confirm e<CR>
:nmap <M-o> <C-O>
```

Then `ALT-o` would have the same effect as `:browse confirm e<CR>`.  But you are already using the "nore" variant, so what you are more likely to do is

```
:nnoremap <C-o> :browse confirm e<CR>
:nnoremap <M-o> <C-O>
```

and this would make `ALT-o` behave like an unmapped `CTRL-O`.

Unless you have a `:cmap` that affects `browse confirm e<CR>`, or you are one of those people who remap `:`, then it does not matter whether you use `:nmap` or `:nnoremap` in the first line above.

```
:help :noremap
```